# Ito's lemma on $X_t=3^{W_t}$

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I need to apply Ito's lemma on $3^{W_t}$, where $W_t$ is a standard brownian motion.
I am not sure how to do this

$X_t=3^{W_t}$

So do I take $f(x)=3^x$ and then apply Ito's lemma? So I get something with

$df(W_t)=\frac{\log^2(3)}{2}3^{W_t}dt+\log(3)3^{W_t}dW_t$

Comment: So you think that $f(x)=3^x$ yields $f'(x)=\log3$ and $f''(x)=\log^23$?

Comment: oh sorry forgot the $3^x$

Comment: So, question solved?

Comment: Is this the correct answer?

Comment: ?? Of course it is, what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Yes I don't know, I was a bit insecure about it, was not used to this form with the logs and all. Was different from what I was used to.